# Threading approch in Apache Camel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.8 and I'm consuming `.csv` files from a directory which is routed to `bean.<br>`.

The `.csv` processing in the bean may take few minutes.

Is it a good approach to move the `.csv` data processing into a separate thread in order to eliminate the long readLock time?

Comment: Fixed grammar and added more tags according the question

Comment: IMHO if you know the maximum time range for processing the files, then it can be a foreground (main thread) processing. Otherwise it is wise to go for multithreading (one thread for one csv file), even if one thread fails the impacts will be minimal.